# assert self.selection is not None, "Field %s without selection" % self

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, selection, odoo-13

(Member Model)

```
kin_relation_with_member = fields.Selection(compute='_is_kin_relation', string="Kin Relation")

def _is_kin_relation(self):
    for res in self.kin_line_ids:
        if res.is_kin:
            self.kin_relation_with_member = res.relation_with_member
            break
        else:
            self.kin_relation_with_member = 'Null'
```

(Kin Model)

```
    is_kin = fields.Boolean('Current Next of Kin')

relation_with_member = fields.Selection([
        ('father', 'Father'),
        ('mother', 'Mother'),
        ('brother', 'Brother'),
        ('sister', 'Sister'),
        ('wife', 'Wife'),
        ('husband', 'Husband'),
        ('son', 'Son'),
        ('daughter', 'Daughter'),
        ('other', 'Other'),
    ], required=True)
```

- assert self.selection is not None, "Field %s without selection" % self
- AssertionError: Field res.partner.kin_relation_with_member without selection

I am trying to get the value of 'relation_with_member' from 'kin' Model into 'member' model kin_relation_with_member = fields.Selection(compute='_is_kin_relation', string="Kin Relation")

It throws an error of (assert self.selection is not None, "Field %s without selection" % self)
(AssertionError: Field res.partner.kin_relation_with_member without selection)

Comment: There are two ways one is create a `kin_relation_with_member` as char field otherwise create a selection field with all possible values of `relation_with_member`. Because in compute we will pass key of the selection field and then Odoo will search for that key and assign value with respect to key and in your case there is no key value pair in `kin_relation_with_member` field

Comment: The attribute ``selection`` is mandatory, except in the case of ``related`` or ``extended`` fields.

Comment: hey guys, have you found any solving in this? I also have this error